# How to select a different user to authenticate Livepatch with?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, active-directory, canonical-livepatch

I am an IT Admin and recently set up an Ubuntu 18.04 laptop for one of my users. As apart of the process, I create a local admin account to set things up and join the computer to our Active Directory domain. Once joined, I have the user sign in using their Active Directory account (which has sudo permissions, like the local admin account).

While overseeing this user sign in, the "Welcome to Ubuntu" window appeared and prompted the user to set up Livepatch, fair enough. This is where my issue is. To set up Livepatch (and start software updates) a window appears for the user to authenticate. The problem is there is no option to select a different user. The username is by default the local admin account that only me and my boss have the password to.

How can I change the default user to the user's AD account, or at least let them switch from the local admin to their own?

Comment: 1. they don't need Livepatch for software updates 2. don't you only need to authenticate with livepatch once? why can't you just put in your password?

Comment: And are you aware 18.04 has less than one year of support left?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to log into your UA portal and have a generated token for your subscriptions.  It is what I see on my free personal.  Its not attached to the user id logged but to the machine id. With an account that has sudo rights just issue:

```
sudo ua attach <token>
```

That will configure your UA features.